# Apache config doen't recognize my enviroment variables

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu

When I try to start the apache web server it throws an exception that says that it doesn't recognize the variables in envvars
I included an image for you to see, I believe my envvars file is fine.
sorry if this is a newbie's question but I am a newbie in apache.

[this is the image, top part is the exception, bottom part is the envvars file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKgTQ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you check if `"/var/run/apache2"` folder is not missing?
If yes, you can try creating the folder:

```
mkdir /var/run/apache2
```

After that, please run the following command:

```
source /etc/apache2/envvars
```

Lastly, you can restart your apache:

```
sudo systemctl stop apache2
sudo systemctl start apache2
```

or

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```